# Java: Sorting unsorted array in descending order

Tags: java

I have an unsorted array of objects.  I need to know how I can sort my array in descending order, according to the highest value inside the objects.

I need to do this using for loops, not the easy way.

I had done this but it seems there is a problem:

```
student[] temp=new student[s.length];

for (int i=0;i<s.length;i++)
{
    if (s[i].GetGpa() > s[i + 1].GetGpa())
    {
        temp[i] = s[i];
    }
}
```

How should I do it using for loops?

Comment: Seems like this is a homework assignment - Bader needs to do it the hard way, without built-in sorts.  
@Bader: get a book on sort algorithms.

Comment: @Bader - What is "the easy way"?. If this is homework you should tag it as such.

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694751/java-array-sort-descending http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946668/sorting-using-comparator-descending-order-user-defined-classes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you started. You'll need to create your own [`Comparator`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and then call [`Collections.Sort()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29).

```
Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest looking at the Wikipedia article for [sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm). Your code fails because you compare each element only with the next one - but that's not a sorting algorithm at all, because in order to be correctly placed in the first position, an element needs to be bigger than *all* other elements, not just the next one.

Also, Using a lowercase class name is very much against Java coding standards.

Comment: and also methods :

getGpa() - nice Java;
GetGpa() - C# like

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Student implements Comparable { ... }
    Arrays.sort(students);
    List<Object> list = Arrays.asList(students);
    Collections.reverse(list);
    students = list.toArray();
```

Comment: This won't work because you need to call GetGpa() on each student object to do the comparison.

Comment: uff, yes my bad
but maybe implements Comparable can save it

Comment: Yes, that's basically what I suggested.

Comment: your fingers are little bit faster than mine :) you replied few seconds before me, but yes you are right

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int j=0;j<s.length;j++) {
    for (int i=0;i<s.length - 1 - j;i++)
    {
        if (s[i].GetGpa() > s[i + 1].GetGpa())
        {
            student temp = s[i];
            s[i] = s[i+1];
            s[i+1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there is a problem come when i put this code 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
 at main_function.main(main_function.java:35)

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++)
{
    for(int j=i+1;j<s.length;j++)
    {
        if(s[j].GetGpa()>s[i].GetGpa())
        {
            student[] temp=new student[5];
            temp[j]=s[j];
            s[j]=s[i];
            s[i]=temp[j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `new student[5]` will create a fixed array. Attempting to use an index beyond 4 (0-4 is 5 values) will cause an `Exception`.
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Also here's an applet that demonstrates the different sorting algorithms: http://www.cs.oswego.edu/~mohammad/classes/csc241/samples/sort/Sort2-E.html