# java - alphabetical order (list)

Tags: java, arraylist, alphabetical

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sort List Alphabetically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708698/sort-list-alphabetically)

how do i store my inputs in alphabetical order, i am inputting names into an arraylist:

```
    persons.add(person);
```

How to do that?

Comment: Just use Sort method of Collection where you pass the persons list.

Comment: Why don't you guys do your homework TOGETHER: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946668/sorting-using-comparator-descending-order-user-defined-classes. It's called a social activity :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
 java.util.Collections.sort(people);
```

Answer (score 9):

implements `Comparator< T >` interface

```
class A implements Comparator < Person > {

    @Override
    public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
        if(o1.getName() != null && o2.getName() != null){
            return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
        }

        return 0;
    }

}
```

then use `Collections.sort(/* list here */, /* comparator here*/)`

Answer (score 5):

```
Collection<Person> listPeople = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

The class Person.java will implements Comparable

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person>{

public int compareTo(Person person) {
  if(this.name != null && person.name != null){
   return this.name.compareToIgnoreCase(person.name);
  }
  return 0;
 }

}
```

Once you have this, in the class you're adding people, when you're done adding, type:

```
Collections.sort(listPeople);
```

Comment: java.util.ArrayList() doesn't offer a sort() method! what programming language are you talking about?

Comment: My bad, its Collections.sort(listPeople);

Comment: Weird.  I only get this error if I compile from the command line -- in Eclipse `ArrayList` totally has a `.sort` method.  Maybe it's a version issue?

Comment: In Java 7, ArrayList does not have sort method. In Java 8, it has.

Answer (score 0):

use TreeSet instead of ArrayList

Comment: No, the thing is that i have to use ArrayList because i have to learn it.

Comment: That's not really a very good answer. TreeSet is a set, not a list. If he follows blindly this answer, he could go into problems (notably, no more duplicate elements) without knowing why.

Comment: The question was how to store the elements in alphabetical order, no restrictions on the collection in the question. The fact that he is using array list doesn't mean anything.