# java - cannot find symbol (arrayList sort collection)

Tags: java, collections

Hi i run into a problem when sorting an arrayList as following (and yes i have imported util):

```
    Collections.sort(personer);
```

I have this list:

```
private List<Person> personer;

public Register() {
    personer = new ArrayList<Person>();
}
```

But i got the error:

> mittscript.java:45: cannot find symbol
>   symbol  : method
>   sort(java.util.List) location:
>   class java.util.Collections
>                   Collections.sort(personer);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I answered you in your other post [java - alphabetical order (list)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518997/java-alphabetical-order-list/4519046#4519046)

I believe if you do it, will fix your problems.

> ```
> Collection<Person> listPeople = new ArrayList<Person>();
> ```
>
> The class Person.java will implements
>   Comparable
>
> ```
> public class Person implements Comparable<Person>{
>
> public int compareTo(Person person) {
>   if(this.name != null && person.name != null){
>    return this.name.compareToIgnoreCase(person.name);
>   }
>   return 0;
>  }
>
> }
> ```
>
> Once you have this, in the class
>   you're adding people, when you're done
>   adding, type:
>
> ```
> Collections.sort(listPeople);
> ```

Answer (score 2):

There're two `sort` methods in `Collections`. You can either make `Person` implement `Comparable` interface, or provide comparator as a second argument into `sort`.
Otherwise, there's no way for JVM to know which `Person` object is 'bigger' or 'smaller' than another.

[See the docs for details.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)

So, option 1

```
class Person implements Comparable {
    ...
}

Collections.sort(list);
```

and option 2

```
Collections.sort(list, myCustomComparator);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should implement `Comparable < T > Interface`