# How to fill a spinner from a database and ORDER BY

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to fill a spinner from my database, but when I get the data does not want them sorted in order by year even indicating this in the query.

This is how I get the data

```
public Set<String> getAllData(int getData,String[] args, String qry) {
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

    String selectQuery = qry ;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery , args);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            set.add(cursor.getString(getData));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return set;
}
```

and this is the query

```
        String myQry = "SELECT * FROM Car ORDER BY year";
```

and loading the spinner

```
private void loadSpinner(Spinner mySpinner, int getData, String[] args, String qry) {

    // here i used Set Because Set doesn't allow duplicates.
    Set<String> set = db.getAllData(getData, args, qry);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(set);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    mySpinner.setWillNotDraw(false);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HashSet doesn't keep insertion order, try a LinkedHashSet.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a HashSet which does not guarantee the order of insertion. Use a list or a sorted set...

Answer (score 0):

```
Collections.sort(list, new YourComparator));

            class YourComparator implements Comparator<String>{
                .
                .
                .
```

[See this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1946845/1103316)
                }
            }