# Sort two ArrayLists, one relative to the other

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to sort one `ArrayList` used to display to the user:

```
String[] listOne = {whip, amulet, cape};
```

Then sort a second `ArrayList` used as backed data relative to the first list being sort:

```
String[] listTwo = {abyssal_whip, amulet_of_power, strength_cape};
```

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: If they are related, why not store them in a `Map`?

Comment: because I'm new to java and I dont really know anything about maps, but I will look into it thanks

Comment: Here you go, for a start : http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/java-map-example/

Comment: Also, if you use `TreeMap` it will store all the values in sorted order by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't store two related pieces of data in separate arrays.

Instead create a custom Object that contains both pieces of data. Then you can implement `Comparable` on your class or write a custom `Comparator` to do the sorting for you.

For example check out: [Sorting using Comparator- Descending order (User defined classes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946668/sorting-using-comparator-descending-order-user-defined-classes/1947527#1947527)

for an example that shows you how to:

1. create a custom Object
2. create a custom `Comparator` or implement `Comparable`.
3. use the Collections class to do the sorting.

Comment: thanks camickr that works perfectly, just one thing hope its proberbly somthing dumb, I made the new object but the only way I can create a new List is by creating it in that class then I'm calling the list statically from there how can I create the list from another class?