# Sort array as ascending

Tags: java

So i have HashMap which i convert it to Object so i can sort it by value, now by default i sort it as descending, but i would need other option too to sort it as ascending.

I used simple array sort:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> prefMap = getMyList();

Object[] a = prefMap.entrySet().toArray();

Arrays.sort(a, new Comparator() {
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        return ((Map.Entry<String, Integer>) o2).getValue()
                .compareTo(((Map.Entry<String, Integer>) o1).getValue());0
    }
});
```

The upper code works for descending, should i just compare with if/else if i want to sort them as ascending?

Comment: just swap `o2` with `o1` to compare it ascending

Comment: If you are working with Java 8+, use `lambda` or `method reference`.

Comment: And please: avoid using **raw** types. That should be a `Comparator<Integer>`, then you wouldnt need to use Object inside!

Comment: @GhostCat you probably meant `Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>` OP's sorting an array created from the entry set

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/1946723/1531124 answer from the duplicated question for example.

Comment: @Lino Yes, correct.

Answer (score 1):

To sort ascending, you may simply call the [reversed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reversed--) version of your `Comparator` :

```
Arrays.sort(a, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {

    public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> o2) {
        return (o2).getValue().compareTo((o1).getValue());
    }

}.reversed()); // <-- see here
```

Comment: Same here: please dont copy code blindly - consider fixing the raw type usage.

Answer (score 0):

Swap o2 and o1 in compareTo, you get it ascending....

```
HashMap<String, Integer> prefMap = getMyList();    
Object[] a = prefMap.entrySet().toArray();   
Arrays.sort(a, new Comparator() {
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        return ((Map.Entry<String, Integer>) o1).getValue()
                .compareTo(((Map.Entry<String, Integer>) o2).getValue());
    }
});
```

Comment: Sigh. Instead of just copying that code, at least go in and drop the *raw* type usage.