# Sort JSON Array from JSON Objects in Android?

Tags: java, android, service, retrofit, okhttp

I have the next JSON response:

```
[{
    format: "jpeg",
    id: 001,
    author: "Mery Rose"
},
{
    format: "jpeg",
    id:002,
    author: "Alex Turner"

}
```

With this Get call, I obtain by ID order: 001, 002

```
@GET("/list")
Call<ArrayList<Groups>> imageList();
```

I need to sort by an author to obtain first Alex an then Mery.

A little help pls.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think **Retrofit** is providing in-build sort on response directly.

For sorting response you have to do it manually using **[comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946668/sorting-using-comparator-descending-order-user-defined-classes)**
like below

```
Collections.sort(imageList, new Comparator<Groups>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Groups g1, Person g2) {
        return g1.getAuthor().compareTo(g2.getAuthor());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Collections like this

```
Collections.sort(imageList, new Comparator<Groups>() {
public int compare(Groups G1, Groups G2) {
    return G1.getAuthor().compareTo(G2.getAuthor());
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to @NJ's answer, you could use new Java 8 [`Comparator.comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) factory, where you can provide a function that extracts the values to be used when comparing objects.

```
Collections.sort(imageList, Comparator.comparing(Groups::getAuthor));
```