# Order JComboBox Elements in Alphabetical Order

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

The following method is from a class that extends `DefaultComboBoxModel`:

```
public void addGroups() {

    removeAllElements();
    ListModel listModel = ((AutoDataProvider) dataProvider).getXmlJobCustom().getJobList();
    ImageIcon imageIcon;
    GroupModel groupModel;
    for (int i = 0;i < listModel.getSize();i++) {
        XmlJobCustomElem elementAt = (XmlJobCustomElem) listModel.getElementAt(i);
        String group = elementAt.getGroup();

        if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(group)) {
            if (group.equalsIgnoreCase("WebServices")){
                imageIcon = Res.getIcon(Constants.ICO + "$WS");
            }
            else if (group.equalsIgnoreCase("file transfer") || group.equalsIgnoreCase("transfert de fichiers")){
                imageIcon = Res.getIcon(Constants.ICO + "$FT");
            }
            else if (group.equalsIgnoreCase("json")){
                imageIcon =  Res.getIcon(Constants.ICO + "$JSON");
            }
            else if (group.toLowerCase().contains("aws")){
                imageIcon = Res.getIcon(Constants.ICO + "$AWS");
            } else {
                imageIcon = Res.getDefIcon(Res.getUserLocalPath() + "/" + XmlJobCustom.ICONS_DIR + "/" + XmlJobCustom.ICONS + elementAt.getId(), Constants.ICO + "$Job.Type." + Job.JOB_CUSTOM);
            }
            groupModel = new GroupModel(imageIcon, group);

            if (getIndexOf(groupModel) ==-1 ){
                addElement(groupModel);
            }
        } else if (StringUtils.isEmpty(group)){
            imageIcon = Res.getIcon(Constants.ICO + "$Job.Type" +"."+ 0);
            groupModel = new GroupModel(imageIcon, "Default");
            if (getIndexOf(groupModel) == -1 ){
                addElement(groupModel);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Explanation**: What I'm doing here is analyse the information that I'm getting from an xml file that contains several elements. Here's an example:

```
<Job id="job password" name="job password" group="AWS S3">
    <params>
        <param id="env" name="environment" desc="Python environment" default="default" mandatory="yes"/>
        <param id="passwordid" name="passwd" type="password" desc="passwd" mandatory="yes"/>
    </params>
    <actions>
        <action id="start">
            <params>
                <param prefix="env">env</param>
                <param prefix="--connector">Connector</param>
            </params>
        </action>
    </actions>
</Job>
```

Focus on the first line. Do you see the parameter `group`? That's what the search is based on. If it's empty, it means the element belongs to the `default` group. If it's not empty, it means I should add it as a new group to the JComboBox of groups with its icon (each element of the JComboBox has an Icon and a String that refers to its name).

Everything is working fine except for one little thing. The elements aren't sorted in alphabetical order which is not practical.

I thought about using Collections.sort(), but the problem here is that I don't have a list or an Array. I have a `DefaultComboBoxModel` that has no methods to sort its elements that way.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can solve it as per Camickr's solution, or create your own sorted model by extending the abstract model class and basing the data structure on a TreeSet or other sorted collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but the problem here is that I don't have a list or an Array. I have a DefaultComboBoxModel that has no methods to sort its elements that way.

So you:

1. copy the elements from the DefaultComboBoxModel to an Array
2. sort the Array
3. recreate the model using the Array.
4. add the model to the combo box

Comment: Thank you. One tiny problem though, the elements of the DefaultComboBoxModel are instances of `GroupModel` ( a class that I created and which has an Icon and a String as its variables). I'm definitely missing something here, but I thought you can only use the `sort()` on Strings, not Objects?

Comment: You can sort any object if the object implements `Comparable` or if you create a `Comparator`. The choice is yours. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946668/sorting-using-comparator-descending-order-user-defined-classes/1947527#1947527 for a basic example of both approaches.

Comment: Thank you for your time.