# How to find sort order in compare method Java

Tags: java, sorting

In short the question is how can we find inside `compare` method of `Comparator` implementation whether sort order is `ascending` (simple) or `descending` (reversed). One method I found is to place instanceof check for `ReverseOrder` class. But that is highly unreliable, as there are many implementations of `Comparator` class for reverse order.

In other words, what if we have to write a comparator, which should not allow reversed(or descending) order.

Comment: I feel like the answer is: You don't.

Comment: Comparators always sort in ascending order, for their own definition of ascending.

Comment: I think this will answer your question, https://stackoverflow.com/a/1946845/4188827

Comment: When you write a comparator, *you* decide which order it implements. What comparator do you want to check with instanceof? Your own? And what ReverseOrder class? There is no such class in the standard API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't.  There is absolutely no way to prevent a `Comparator` being converted to a descending-order comparator.  If you are given a `Comparator`, then that defines ascending order, even if it's descending relative to another comparator.

If there is one unique, ascending order that you always want to use, then the type should implement `Comparable`, instead of having a `Comparator`, and you should use the natural ordering of the type.