# Sort String Length, but reversed (longest String first)

Tags: java, sorting, compare, reverse

I have to do an excercise where i have to write a method orderQuestionsByLength(), which should sort questions by its length (descending)

the following code works (but it's not sorted descending):

```
`public void orderQuestionsByLength(){
        Collections.sort(questions,Comparator.comparing(question -> question.getText().length())); 
        for (Question question : questions){                                                       
            System.out.println(question);
        }
    }`
```

as soon as i add .reversed() my IDE throws an error **Cannot resolve method 'getText' in 'Object'** even though i have a method getText() and it worked before adding .reversed()

it drives me crazy, bc i don't know how to solve the problem, gpt says my code is right (not saying that i should rely on gpt, but i have another method where i sort integers descending, where i used reversed() without any problems

Comment: if order ascending works fine and you use `length()` which returns a number, sorting in descending (reverse) would be just negating `length()` to be `comparing(question -> -1 * question.getText().length())`

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1946668/642706

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can sometimes happen because the Comparator.comparing method can't correctly infer the type of the lambda parameter when it's chained with .reversed().

To solve this issue, you can provide **explicit type information in the lambda** expression. Here's how you can modify your `orderQuestionsByLength` method with `(String question) -> …`.

```java
public void orderQuestionsByLength() {
    Collections.sort(questions, Comparator.comparing((Question question) -> question.getText().length()).reversed()); 
    for (Question question : questions) {                                                       
        System.out.println(question);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `Comparator#reversed`.

Be careful in your syntax. Call `reversed` *after* producing the comparator with `Comparator.comparing`.

- `Comparator.comparing` is a `static` method call, producing an instance (an object).
- `Comparator#reversed` is an instance method call, producing another object.

As pointed out in [Answer by CHF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77827598/642706), you may need to be explicit with the data type of the argument passed to the lambda: `( String question ) -> …`.

```java
public void orderQuestionsByLength()
{
    Collections.sort( 
        questions, 
        Comparator
            .comparing( ( String question ) -> question.getText().length() )  // Static method call. 
            .reversed()  // Instance method call. 
    ); 
    questions.forEach( System.out :: println ) ;  
}
```

By the way, you can collapse that `for` loop by using `Collections#forEach` with a method reference, as seen above.

---

Full example app code:

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Infer
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        Comparator < Question > comparator =
                Comparator
                        .comparing ( ( Question question ) -> question.text ( ).length ( ) )
                        .reversed ( );

        ArrayList < Question > questions =
                new ArrayList <> (
                        List.of (
                                new Question ( "alpha" , 1 ) ,
                                new Question ( "b" , 2 ) ,
                                new Question ( "gamma" , 3 )
                        )
                );
        questions.sort ( comparator );
        questions.forEach ( System.out :: println );
    }
}

record Question( String text , int points ) { }
```

Comment: i copy-pasted your code and i still get the same error. i solved the problem by clarifying the explicit type 

 Collections.sort(questions,Comparator.comparing((Question question)-> question.getText().length()).reversed());

Comment: @lauMolau Good. I use the explicit type routinely to be more clear to the human reader. What exactly is the type of `questions`? I’m surprised the compiler could not infer the type.

Comment: questions is an ArrayList for the type Question only. And Question consists of 2 variables (String text, and int points)